# Why does javascript on the page stop the drop down menu working?

Tags: javascript, navigation, dropdown

I have just inserted a javascript world clock via a text doc and a CEWP. 
However now that this is functional on my page I cannot see my drop downs from the top nav bar. It was working fine before I put the javascript in.
Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly ended up being the error here? I have literally this EXACT same issue.

Comment: Im assuming its the one marked below. I use a different clock now anyway, the original one was riddled with errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a script conflict, error in the world clock that's not visible, CSS override, etc. One thing you can try is opening the Developer toolbar in IE (press F12) and click the script tab, then click Start Debugging. That should reload your page and throw any script errors if there are any.

However, chances are it's a CSS issue, does the world clock have it's own CSS references? Is it overriding any OOTB SharePoint classes? Can you point us to the script?

Comment: +1 it is either a conflict or an error. If it a conflict then you might want to scope your included javascript. http://tech.myemma.com/iifes-javascript-control-variable-scope/

Comment: +1 A script error in the script you pasted, or a conflict would prevent any other JavaScript on the page from executing.

Comment: David, followed the debugging steps you outlined and the only thing it returned was this: "SCRIPT5009: '_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames' is undefined Home2.aspx, line 150 character 1". Im not great with script, only very basic javascript so any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. If not, thanks for your help already

Comment: Remove the web part and debug again, see if this is an existent error or not. Sometimes SP will error for the fun of it :/